# How i can show the Direct parent folder name/title inside my PnP Modern Search web part's Search Results

Tags: sharepoint-online, search-results, pnp

I have added this PnP Search Results, to only show folders with name ="Specs" inside a specific document library :-

[image]

and we got this valid results:-

[image]

Our folder structure looks as follow:-

Documents

1. CustomerA

- Main
- General
- Specs

2. CustomerB

- Main
- General
- Specs

3. CustomerC

- Main
- General
- Specs

so currently inside the Search results it will only show the sub-folder names, but we need to know to which parent folder (customerA or customerB or CustomerC) this "Specs" folder belongs.. is there a way to do this?

Thanks